# drawing on Image View android

Tags: android, android-canvas, android-imageview

Can anybody help me with how to draw a circle of specific radius on an `ImageView` every time pixel values (centers for the circle to be drawn) are received from another `Activity`?

Answer (score 3):

Extend `ImageView` and override `onDraw(Canvas c)` method - add `c.drawCirle(x,y,radius,Paint)`

Or for drawing circle you can use pure Canvas as well.

I tried this way but still no luck

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {
private MyImageView myImageView;
 float x, y;
 float [] loc;
float radius = 50;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_show_location);
    myImageView = (MyImageView) findViewById(R.id.mapimageView);
    myImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.mymap);

    //Receiving location information(x/y pixels array) from myLocation Activity         
        Intent i = getIntent();     
        loc = i.getFloatArrayExtra("Location");

}
public class MyImageView extends ImageView
{

    public MyImageView(Context context) {
        super(context);         
    }
    // Constructor for inflating via XML
   public MyImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
   super(context, attrs);         
    }


            @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        Paint p = new Paint();
        x= loc[0];
        y=loc[1];
        p.setColor(Color.RED);
        p.setStrokeWidth(2);        
        canvas.drawCircle(x, y, radius, p);
    }       
}
```

And in xml change `<ImageView`  to `your.package.name.MyImageView`

// EDIT Im writing it only from memmory,so there could be typos

Comment: I appreciate ur help ..can anybody have a look at of my code for the mistakes I made ..thanks ;)

Comment: thank u for the help ..i am facing a problem the drawing being using the screen pixel position instead of the image view ..any suggestion how to modify for the offset ..thanks

Comment: myImageView.getLeft() myImageView.getTop(); shold get x and y offset of the imageview from the parent layout, maybe there could be offset from android top bar height too, but im not sure, just try it.